# Prove that $ab \leq \frac14$ and $ (1+1/a)(1+1/b)\ge 9$ when $a+b=1, a \ge 0, b \ge 0$

Tags: inequality

Our teacher gave us some identities firstly and said we could use one of them to prove it. The identities are: $$\frac{(a^2+b^2)}{2}≥\left(\frac{(a+b)}{2}\right)^2$$ $$(x+y)^2≥2xy$$ and $$\frac{(x+y)}{2} \ge \sqrt{xy}$$

Here's what I did to solve this exercise:

$$\frac{a+b}2 \ge \sqrt{ab} \implies \frac12 \ge \sqrt{ab} \implies \frac14\ge ab \implies ab\le\frac14$$

$$\left(1+\frac1a\right)\left(1+\frac1b\right) = 1+\frac1b+\frac1a+\frac1{ab} \ge 9 \Rightarrow \frac{a+b+1}{ab}\ge8 \Rightarrow \frac2{ab}\ge8 \Rightarrow 2\le8ab \Rightarrow ab\le\frac14$$

I came to a known point, but I'm not sure that this is the right form. If there is any other more clear proof please show it to me.

Comment: The first identity doesn't seem right.  Can you check it?  Or, is it an assumption?

Comment: The post is still confusing. Can you edit please? Are you given $a^2+b^2=(a+b)/2$ and asked to prove the 2 inequalities in the title?

Comment: I made a change

Comment: From where you stopped, $$\frac{a+b+1}{ab}+1 = \frac{2}{ab}+1 \ge \frac2{1/4}+1 = 9$$

Comment: @seda That's better, though it is not equality, the LHS can be larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the inequality$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\ge\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2$$is used, then we can deduce that $a^2+b^2\ge2ab$ must hold.  This can be seen from squaring the terms on the LHS and simplifying the resulting expression.

Now, $$ab\le\frac12(a^2+b^2)=\frac{(a+b)^2-2ab}{2}=\frac12-ab$$This implies that $$2ab\le\frac12$$which in turn gives the first inequality$$ab\le\frac14$$

For the second inequality, we have
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{b}\right)=1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{ab}=1+\frac{a+b+1}{ab}=1+\frac{2}{ab}$$But we just showed that $ab\le\frac14$ which means that $\frac{1}{ab}\ge 4$.  Using this, we find $$\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{b}\right)\ge1+(2)(4)=9$$and that completes the proof for the second inequality!

Comment: who said that a=b? We haven't learnt this method

Comment: @seda The first condition you wrote was $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}=\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2$. If you square the terms on the RHS and simplify, you will get $a^2+b^2-2ab=0$.  But $a^2+b^2-2ab=(a-b)^2$=0.  So, $a$ must be equal to $b$.

Comment: Please check it again. I made a mistake and I corrected it.

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot for your work! I really appreciate it! I am given the chance just to accept answers and that's what I did.

Comment: Thank you!!!!  Let me know if you need help with other problems as they arise.

Answer (score 4):

Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{a}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{b}\right)\ge\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ab}}\right)^2\ge (1+2)^2=9$$

Comment: We didn't prove it in class. Can you find a way using the identities I showed?

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the inequality from the equation
$$
1=(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2\\
0\le(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2
$$
to get
$$
1\ge4ab\implies\frac14\ge ab\tag{1}
$$
Apply $(1)$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1a\right)\left(1+\frac1b\right)
&=1+\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1{ab}\\
&=1+\frac{a+b}{ab}+\frac1{ab}\\[3pt]
&=1+\frac2{ab}\\[3pt]
&\ge1+\frac2{1/4}\\[8pt]
&=9\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you're only allowed to use $x+y\geq 2\sqrt{xy}$ (for $x,y\geq 0$), then
$$
1=a+b\geq2\sqrt{ab}\implies ab\leq\frac{1}{4}
$$
and
$$
(1+1/a)(1+1/b)=1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{ab}\geq 1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{ab}}+\frac{1}{ab}\geq1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{1/4}}+\frac{1}{1/4}=9.
$$